# Missing \endgroup error for Beamer standalone with subpreambles option

Tags: beamer, errors, standalone

I am trying to use Martin Scharrer's nifty `standalone` package to put a Beamer animation into a standalone file.  Here is a minimal example that demonstrates the error I am running into.  The subfile, creatively named `subfile.tex`, that I am using is:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\mytext}{Hello world!}

\begin{document}%
\begin{standaloneframe}{Subfile}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \onslide<+->{\draw[red] (0,0) circle (3pt);}
    \onslide<+->{\draw[blue] (1,1) circle (3pt);}
    \onslide<+->{\draw[green] (2,0) circle (3pt);}
    \onslide<+->{\node at (1,2) {\mytext};}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{standaloneframe}%
\end{document}
```

On its own, this subfile compiles as expected.

The main file, named `mainfile.tex`, that I am using is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}

%\usepackage{tikz}
%\newcommand*{\mytext}{Hello world!}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Main file}
  \input{subfile.tex}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this main file with `pdflatex mainfile.tex`, I get an error:

```
Runaway argument?
%\begin {standaloneframe}{Subfile}\begin {tikzpicture}\onslide <+->{\draw \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \sa@@endinput.
```

When I try a second run of `pdflatex mainfile.tex`, this runaway argument error disappears, but another error takes its place:  Extra `}`, or forgotten `\endgroup`.  I use `X` at the prompt to quit compilation after the error.  Subsequent runs of `pdflatex mainfile.tex` continue to give this missing `\endgroup` error.

I have noticed a few things:

- If I remove the `subpreambles=true` option and uncomment the two lines of copied preamble
  (`\usepackage{tikz}` and `\newcommand*{\mytext}{Hello world!}`), this modified main file
  compiles as expected.
- However, if I *keep* the `subpreambles=true` option but uncomment the two lines of copied preamble, I get the same error when I try to compile.  This suggests that something goes wrong in the `subpreambles=true` option.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?  In his comment below, Martin Scharrer mentions that multiple compilation runs work for him.  I'm not sure why I seem to be unable to get multiple compilation runs to work for me.

Comment: The error only occurs at the first compiler run but disappears in the second and following compiler runs. This is definitively some bug in `standalone`. The `beamer` support isn't that great I have to confess. I will have a closer look at this. Feel free to report such issues at https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues.

Comment: If I call `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode mainfile` as the first run, then subsequent runs are performed regularly.

Comment: I now added a fix for this to the hg repository of `standalone` (https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/). The error is caused by a clean-up macro which should end the reading of the subfile preamble once `\begin{document}` is reached, but still has to discard everything in the same line of it. Having a `%` after it is actually a bad idea, but the real problem seems to be the changed `\endlinechar`. The new code resets it and discards anything verbatim to exclude any such issues. I will publish a bugfix release soon.

Comment: I just uploaded v1.1b of `standalone` which fixes this issue. I will also close this question as "too localized" (in time) as it is local practice for package bugs.

Comment: @MartinScharrer The v1.1b release of `standalone` works great!  Thanks so much for your help!  I wish I could give a bounty for your efforts.